# Initialize the common controls to use StatusBar (ICC_WIN95_CLASSES vs ICC_BAR_CLASSES)

Tags: c, winapi

I need to initialize the common controls to use the StatusBar control, but I am not sure what value I should use. I found these two values in the `INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **ICC_BAR_CLASSES**
>
> Load toolbar, status bar, trackbar, and tooltip control classes.
>
> **ICC_WIN95_CLASSES**
>
> Load animate control, header, hot key, list-view, progress bar, status
>   bar, tab, tooltip, toolbar, trackbar, tree-view, and up-down control
>   classes.

I am guessing that `ICC_WIN95_CLASSES` should be used if I am creating an application for Windows 95, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the values of the symbols you'll see that `ICC_WIN95_CLASSES` includes `ICC_BAR_CLASSES` within it:

```
#define ICC_BAR_CLASSES        0x00000004 // toolbar, statusbar, trackbar, 
#define ICC_WIN95_CLASSES      0x000000FF
```

Basically, `ICC_WIN95_CLASSES` includes all of the common controls that existed in Windows 95 (which includes the status bar), but the you can also use the flag on later operating systems (and nobody should be targeting Windows 95 today anyway).

If all you want is the status bar control, `ICC_BAR_CLASSES` is fine and will work on any version of Windows.